# return minimum or less than a particular number - prolog

Tags: prolog

The question requires us to code Prolog that if there is no element in the list
L that is less than A, is satisfied when M is A; otherwise it is satisfied when M
is the minimum of the list L

```
minLessThan([],A,A).
minLessThan([H|T], A, M) :-
   H >= A,
   M is A,
   minLessThan(T, A, M).
minLessThan([H|T], A, M) :-
   H < A,
   M is H,
   minLessThan(T, A, M).
```

Now that, my result valids for the first part of the sentence, however it keeps returns me false when the M is the minimum of the list L, i assume that the problem occurs when the list L is empty, which it returns the A, any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is homework I am only going to give you some advice:

For what you are trying to do, you should not instantiate M in the second and third clause until the recursive step.
That is, you don't have to put the `M is A` and `M is H` because M will get instantiated in the base case (the first clause).

Also, the recursive call in the third clause should use `H` instead of `A` as the second argument, because you have found an item less than the current minimum.

Note that the second parameter of `minLessThan` can be read as "the current minimum found", so you should call the procedure giving some initial value, otherwise instantiation errors will occur.

Comment: Thx, i have just understood what you meant in the answer. How stupid am i that didnt discover the use of the second parameter. Thx for the help.Btw, should I post the corrected code here? first time user here.

Comment: you can if you want complementary advice about it. Or just if you want us to check it to tell you if it's fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
minLessThan([],A,A).

minLessThan([H|T], A, M) :-
    H >= A,
    minLessThan(T, A, M).

minLessThan([H|T], A, M) :-
    H < A,
    minLessThan(T, H, M).
```

Here is my edited answer, works fine for now .